# Floating divs top to bottom

Tags: html, css

I'm making a productscreen, I've made a Paint example what i've in mind. [image: Example productscreen]

The big black block is the productView with an sliding container in the back. I want to alphabetically order those products (All these little roundend blocks are products in a divs). But this order is "A" from beginning and 'Z' to end of slindingcontainer.

I want to order the products like the red line. I now have a second container with an modules, only this breaks my code.

Is there an other way to order the products like my example drawing?

**Update** - My code now:

```
            <?php
            if(!empty($productByType)){
                for($i=0;$i < count($productByType); $i++){

                    $id = $productByType[$i]['id'];
                    $title = $productByType[$i]['title'];
                    $img = base_url('/img/producten/'.$productByType[$i]["img"]);

                    if($i % 2 == 0){
                        echo '<div class="seperatorforproduct">';
                        //0,2,4,6,8
                    }

                    ============
                    Content divs

                    **Example of one product:** (Using modal from bootstrap)

                    echo '<div class="button btnstyle">';
                    echo '<div class="imgbtn">';    
                    //  <!-- Picture-->
                    echo '<img src="'.$img.'" title="'.$title.'" alt="'.$title.'" data-toggle="modal" href="#modal'.$id.'" />';
                    echo '</div>';  
                    echo '<div class="txtbtn txtstyle">';   
                    echo '<a class="btn" data-toggle="modal" href="#modal'.$id.'" >'.$title.'</a>';
                    echo '</div>';
                    echo '</div>';
                    ?>
                    <div class="modal" style="display:none;" id="modal<?=$id?>">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
                            <h2><?=$title?></h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="modal-left">
                            <img src="<?=$img?>" title="<?=$title?>" alt="<?=$title?>" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-right">
                            <p><?=$productByType[$i]['info']?></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            Telephone number etc.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    ============


                    <?php
                    if($i % 2 == 1 || $i == count($productByType)){
                        // 0,3,6,9,12
                        echo '</div>';
                    }
                }      
            }?>
```

Comment: Always to divs per column ? If yes, wrap them in a parent div and float these parents. If no... more difficult.

Comment: yes, always two divs in a column. The products a generated in PHP from a DB. What i've done now is that a foreach loop is checking and placing al the products. And in this loop a for loop with a modules. Only this breaks my code.

Comment: add some code what u have tried...

Comment: This is the code that is working, only breaks on modules

Comment: Is there another way? Yes. I've used Isotope to achieve similar effects before, although I have never tried your specific ordering. It's built on jQuery. http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Comment: This project is not free for commercial use, but i'm searching now for good alternatives. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/Mzmay/18/

Using PHP you generate the markup like that in fiddle & later you can use the jQuery to do that. I am not sure how to do the same by just using Php.

Comment: I'd tried this, its exactly what i've in mind, only i don't understand the jquery code completely.

Comment: You mean you wish to arrange table cells in this order or tables ?